# Angular undefined after fetch function

Tags: typescript, angular

У меня есть следующая функция.

```
getItems(): any {

    fetch('./assets/data/data.json').then(res => res.json()).then(res => {
      console.log(res);
      return res;
    });

  }
```

В блоке `fetch` функция `console.log` выводит `JSON` содержимое файла. В другом компоненте:

```
items: any;

  constructor(private itemService: ItemService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.items = this.itemService.getItems();

    console.log(this.items);
  }
```

Функция `console.log` выводит `undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что вы ничего не возвращаете

// возвращаем Promise

```
getItems(): Promise<any> {
    return fetch('./assets/data/data.json').then(res => res.json());
}
```

// т.к. это Promise в then получаем результат

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.itemService.getItems().then((res) => {
      this.items = res;
      console.log(this.items);
    });
  }
```

Второй вариант использовать конструкцию async/await

Comment: Спасибо, всё работает, но сделал так, только через `Observable`. Но всё же хотелось узнать почему нельзя с блока `fetch` инициализировать объект, а потом этот объект возвращать?

Comment: Да так правильней и в ангуляре есть встроенный [httpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http) который как раз работает с Observalable. Блок fetch возвращает promise если вы хотите получить значение, то вам нужно воспользоваться конструкцией async/await что заставит ждать результата

Comment: И в вашем первоначальном варианте вы вообще ничего не возвращали т.к. нет return из самой функции getItems()